# Why route asks me show action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I forward the user to the next URL:

```
http://bookworm.az:3000/messages/alizade
```

And in routes I do:

```
get '/messages' => 'messages#index'
get '/messages/:username' => 'messages#index'
```

But it asks me show action. But I want just to show the same `/messages` page.

For example, here it works and did not asks me about show action:

```
get ':username/manage' => 'profiles#index'
```

How can I return the same page without show action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order precedence.

You already have a route that much this pattern. Something like: resources :messages.

To work, move the line:

```
get: '/messages/:username' => 'messages#index'
```

to top of the routes.rb file.

**NOTE From Rails Guide:**

> "Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first."

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html